# I can't find VLC libraries

Tags: linux, opensuse, libvlc

I am writing application to video streaming. My professor from programming gave us instruction but it is for Windows. I am writing it for Linux so I need libs for it `*.so` (I suppose so). This is list for Windows. How I can find counterparts:

> axvlc.dll libvlc.dll libvlccore.dll npvlc.dll

Firstly I installed vlc from my dist repo but I couldn't find libs I was searching in:

> #whereis vlc vlc: /usr/bin/vlc /usr/lib64/vlc /usr/share/vlc

So I downloaded source code and I do `./configure` and `make` but I also couldn't find those libs

Comment: install libvlc-devel

Comment: I found 2 from 4 libvlc and libvlccore. I still don't have axvlc and npvlc

Comment: axvlc is for activeX, no way AFAICS on Linux, for npvlc, install mozilla-plugin-vlc

Comment: I found information that npvlc is droped. libvlcplugin.so is used now

Answer (score 1):

If you on some of Ubuntu clone, you could just run:

```
sudo apt-get install libvlc-dev
```

Comment: openSUSE use zypper than apt-get as default

Comment: sorry, missed OpenSUSE tag